# AndEngine Texture doesn't render on Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4

Tags: android, andengine

I have the following textures in AndEngine 1.

512 x 4096  (PNG Size - 500 x 2415)

2048 x 2048 (PNG Size - 2048 x 2048)

2048 x 2048 (PNG Size - 2048 x 2048)

However some of the textures from the bitmap texture atlas do not show up during gameplay. One thing that surprises me is, the textures are visible on a 3 year old **HTC Wildfire** but they don't show up consistently on **Galaxy Nexus** or **Nexus 4**.

In Galaxy Nexus the few sprites just display white rectangles. And on the Nexus 4 some textures mysteriously disappear. Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I thought OpenGL textures needed to be power of 2s. The first texture you have shouldn't be working on any device. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: One thing you can check for .deepCopy() method for each sprite you have created.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk - the first texture is 512x4096. Both dimensions are powers of two. Textures do not have to be square. OP is saying the png is being loaded into a texture that size. The 500x2415 is the asset size.